# Blank template even after data is loaded: Angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic4

The template is loaded before data is fetched in Angular 8. I have used ngIf directive to load the template only if valid data is there.

In the ts file, the data is loaded(as this can be seen in the attached image, I inspected using Chrome debugger tools), which is not reflected in the template.

How to load the data before and reflect the changes in the template? And how to make the template updated with the dynamic changes?

[image]
The below code snippet is from the template:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="snapshot" class='fund-snapshot-list' padding id='fund-snapshot-list-{{symbol}}'>

    <ion-item color="secondary">
      <ion-label id='fund-snapshot-list-index-{{symbol}}'>Index Value ({{index}})</ion-label>
      <ion-label id='fund-snapshot-list-index-value-{{symbol}}' text-right>{{snapshot.indexValue | number:'1.2-2'}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item color="secondary">
      <ion-label id='fund-snapshot-list-index-dividend-{{symbol}}' class='custom-width-label'>Index Dividend Yield
      </ion-label>
      <ion-label id='fund-snapshot-list-index-dividend-value-{{symbol}}' text-right>
        {{snapshot.indexDividendYield | number:'1.2-2'}}%</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

The ts file:

```
export class FundSnapshotComponent {
snapshot: FundSnapshot;

constructor(private readonly cmsService: CmsService) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.snapshotSubscription = this.cmsService.getSectorSnapshots()
      .subscribe(snapshots => {
        this.snapshot = snapshots.find(snapshot => snapshot.sector === this.symbol);
        this.updateFields(this.snapshot);
      });
}

updateFields(snapshot: FundSnapshot) {
    if (snapshot === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    this.snapshot.indexValue = snapshot.indexValue;
    this.snapshot.indexDividendYield = snapshot.indexDividendYield;
} }
```

[image]

Comment: could you show `ngIf` in template and variable which is checked in template?

Comment: share your code? your template file and your life-cycle hooks events ?

Comment: You can look into angular APP_INITIALIZER https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/

It is used to do things before the app is loaded. You could pre fetch your data using APP_INITIALIZER

and store it in a service. When the template loads it can get the data from that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually the issue with the @ionic/angular 4.7.0 version: **Angular change detection is broken.**

The actual problem was: Navigating to a page directly is working as expected but navigating to another tab, for example, don't.

Upgrade to use **4.7.1 of @ionic/angular framework**, this will solve the issue.

Refer this link for more details: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18894

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the html file content? Like how you do your *ngIf?

In the meantime, maybe you can check against a property of the data not just the main data object.

```
*ngIf=“snapshot && snapshot.sector”
```

Comment: I added the suggestion you made. But the list-item is not showing up. But when I have inspected using chrome debugger tools, the data is there for the snapshot variable. 

The template is rendered before the time data gets loaded and is not getting updated with the data or after the data gets loaded.